# How can I prove the following matrix equality?

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Why is the following equality true?
$$
\left(\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
+ 3 \begin{pmatrix}4 & 6\\-2 & -3\end{pmatrix}\right)^n
= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
+ (4^n-1)\begin{pmatrix}4 & 6\\-2 & -3\end{pmatrix}
.
$$

Also, it might help that:

$$\begin{pmatrix}4 & 6\\\ -2 & -3\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}4 & 6\\\ -2 & -3\end{pmatrix}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to write $\begin{pmatrix}4&6\\-2&-3\end{pmatrix}$ as a sum $D+N$ where $D$ is diagonal and $N$ nilpotent.

Comment: Seems like an easy exercise in induction

Comment: Be careful with your edits, @Nathanael Skrepek. You deleted the coefficient of the second matrix. (And a big thumbs down to everyone who voted to approve the edit.)

Comment: @amd i am sorry. there were so many dollar signs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use binomial formula and the fact that $A^2 = A \Rightarrow A^k = A$

$$(I + 3A)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}3^kA^k =I + A\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}3^k = I + A ((1+3)^n-1) = I +(4^n-1)A$$

Note that you can apply the binomial formula since $IA = AI$.

Comment: You should point the binomial formula is valid because the two matrices commute (might be useful for beginners).

Comment: @Bernard I thought this is trivial but you have just convinced me. So, I added it. :-) Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! One always should think of beginners… I'll remove my comments in a moment.